# Concatenating HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html

Im trying to echo the content of the foreach loop inside div tag but I get an error message. I know my making a mistake in concatenating html and php but Im not sure where I'm making the mistake. Can some one point me in the right direction?

```
<php
  for($i=0; $i<$daysInTheMonth; $i++){
   if($i==$firstDayOfMonth)
     $BeginMonth= true;

    if($BeginMonth){
   $CounterForDays++;

    echo  "<div class=dateContainner> ".$CounterForDays <br/> ;
    foreach ($_POST['mondayTime'] as $Times ){
     echo  "$Times <br>" ;
   }
     ."</div>";
 }
    else
  echo "<div class=dateContainner>  </div>";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: You can't put control structures in the middle of a string

Comment: it seems that I was missing an echo statement before my closing div. Thanks for your comment. Ravinder had the correct lead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
if($BeginMonth){
  $CounterForDays++;
  echo  "<div class=dateContainner> ".$CounterForDays." <br/>" ;
  foreach ($_POST['mondayTime'] as $Times ){
   echo  $Times."<br>" ;
  }
  echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: I see what I did. Thanks. If I want to add this:  echo " <input type="radio" > ".$Times." <br>" ; do I have to open an re open a <?php ?> line inside the quation marks?